# Why does vibrate turn off every time a call is ended?

Tags: calls, vibration

I have a Galaxy S7, MM 6.0.1, rooted/xposed.

Any time a call is ended for any reason, whether it be after an actual conversation, or a manually rejected incoming call, or an automatically blocked/rejected incoming call, vibrate turns off.  I need to know how to stop this from happening.